# How to disable cache for particular block in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, block-cache

I have created a block in header

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">           
                <block class="XXX\ABC\Block\Category\News" name="news" template="XXX_ABC::catalog/product/news.phtml" cacheable="false" />           
        </referenceContainer>
```

I need to disable cache for this block for quote.so i use `cacheable="false"` in this layout.

The cache is disable only for this block in header section (or) full page?

Thanks..

Comment: it will for all.

Comment: But i need to disable cache for particular block...If any solution for do that?

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set your block in controller file :

```
$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
```

After add this line in your controller :

```
$resultPage->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);
```

Clear cache and check your output.

Comment: It use to clear cache only for mentioned block?

Comment: Yes. It's use for specific block. As per my answer, It will just use for customer_account_navigation block only.

Comment: Ok..i will try that

Comment: In controller file ...$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name');
           return $resultPage->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Yes exactly what you write in last second comment. what issue generated? any log or report generated?

Comment: I already check it before upload answer. Please check it there are something going wrong.

Comment: I don't have controller, created the template in default.xml file, so where should we add the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Cacheable and uncacheable pages

Cacheable and uncacheable are terms we use to indicate whether or not a page should be cached at all. (By default, all pages are cacheable.) If any block in a layout is designated as uncacheable, the entire page is uncacheable.

You can see more information [Magento dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html)

Comment: I  need to get quote items...But i can't get the data when the cache is enable..If any alternate solution for get quote items...

Comment: On which page you want to quote items?

Comment: In list page ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `cacheable="false"` will make whole page non-cached.
So the option is you need to use knockout js to render the non cache content, kind of ajax.

Please check here - 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

To gave a view how M2 cache system works you can have a view of this ie. page variations and Identity Interface -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html